# How to handle Internationalization by using Selenium WebDriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Can any one suggest me how to handle internationalization with selenium webdriver and Python by an example.

Found this article but it is with Java

https://nileshdk.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/internationalization-automating-localized-ui-using-selenium-webdriver/

Looking for a approach using Web Driver + Python combination.

Comment: The article has about 5 lines of very simple codesnippets, it is not language dependent - it looks exactly the same in python too. Simply load the text list dynamically based on the current language, that you can specify on any way you like.

Comment: Try to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your `script.py`. This should allow you to use `"utf-8"` encoding

Answer (score 0):

Example for Internationalization with below code:

Editor used: PyCharm

Filename: Internationalization.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from Day_3.csvReader import *

for languages in test_execution():

    firefoxprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    firefoxprofile.set_preference("intl.accept_languages", languages)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxprofile)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")

    text_leftbottom1 = ".//*[@id='fsl']/a["
    text_leftbottom2 = "]"

    for i in range(1, 4):
        for linktext in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(text_leftbottom1 + str(i) + text_leftbottom2):
            print(linktext.text)

    text_rightbottom1 = ".//*[@id='fsr']/a["
    text_rightbottom2 = "]"

    for i in range(1, 3):
        for linktext in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(text_rightbottom1 + str(i) + text_rightbottom2):
            print(linktext.text)
```

CSV File: testsuite.csv

This file contains the name of the languages in which we want to open the site.

Structure of file:

```
Language
pt-BR
fr
```

Method for reading csv file:

import csv as csv

```
def test_execution():
    with open('E:\\Study\\HackerRank_30DaysofCode\\Day_3\\testsuite.csv', 'r+') as file:
        data = csv.DictReader(file)
        result = []
        for row in data:
            result.append((row['Language']))
        return result
```

Feedback most welcome!